# Что нужно сделать, чтобы в поля вводилось информаиця? (Python)

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup, bs4

У меня есть [сайт](https://ekb.zappstore.pro/auth/login), на котором нужно авторизоваться через login и password. Я пытаюсь авторизоваться через скрипт, но это не срабатывает. Ошибок нет. Что я делаю не так? Может я что-то вписал не так(например в словаре authdata)?

Код:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

while True:
    authdata = {'_username': 'Логин', '_password': 'Пароль'}

    session = requests.Session()
    response = session.post('https://ekb.zappstore.pro/auth/login', data=authdata)
    parsedata = session.post('https://ekb.zappstore.pro/routelist') #После авторизации

    html = bs(parsedata.content, 'html.parser')
    items = html.find_all("table", class_="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover")

    for item in items:
        a = item.text
        print(a)
```

Выводит только код страницы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
response = session.post('https://ekb.zappstore.pro/auth/check', data=authdata)
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!